# Dúvida group by + função SUM

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

Tenho um problema em montar uma `query` no meu banco de dados `mysql` para frequência de participantes em um evento.

Tenho uma tabela participante onde tem as informações do participante, e tem as presenças desse participantes nos dias 1, 2 e 3 (as colunas d1, d2, d3) onde armazeno 0 para não frequência e 1 para a frequência no respectivo dia.

Pois bem, agora preciso fazer uma consulta onde me informe quantos dias cada participante inscrito estava presente: 0 (caso não compareça nenhum dia), 1, 2 ou 3 dias, estou fazendo isso com a função `SUM(d1 + d2 + d3)`.

Agora preciso aplicar o `group by` na função `SUM` para agrupar as contagens de quantos participantes estavam presentes em 0, 1, 2 ou 3 dias. Porem recebo o **erro 1056**.

De qual outra maneira posso fazer a seguinte query ?

**Query**

```
SELECT count(*) as cont, SUM(d1 + d2 + d3) as dias
FROM guiatudoonline_cadastro.participantes
GROUP BY dias
```

Comment: Olá  ! seria interessante você adicionar no enunciado da pergunta a descrição do erro 1056 . No caso seria "Error: 1056 SQLSTATE: 42000 (ER_WRONG_GROUP_FIELD)"  a mensagem de erro exibida ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua query não faz o que você diz, a começar pelo "cada participante", já que você não incluiu o identificador do participante no SELECT.

Para saber quantos dias cada participante compareceu, você deveria fazer:

```
SELECT participante, (d1 + d2 + d3) qtde_dias
FROM guiatudoonline_cadastro.participantes
```

Para saber quantos participantes compareceram quantos dias:

```
SELECT (d1 + d2 + d3) qtde_dias, count(*)
FROM guiatudoonline_cadastro.participantes
GROUP BY qtde_dias
```

O SUM() não soma os valores de uma linha, mas entre várias linhas que compartilham o critério de agregação que você especificou. Nas suas queries ele não era necessário.

A primeira query não precisou de critério de agregação porque entendi que cada participante aparece apenas uma vez na consulta, já que d1, d2 e d3 são colunas distintas. Se você tivesse modelado as colunas como (participante, data), então haveria uma agregação por participante e um COUNT(data).